# Problems to run Vaadin (maven) sample project on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

I believe this is specific question regarding Vaadin so if anyone who has an experience with Vaadin can help it will be great.
I am new with Vaadin framework. I worked more then 25 years as Oracle Developer and also wrote some Java programs.

My company is actually migrating Oracle Forms application to Java. As a user User interface layer we are using Vaadin and HTML5

I have installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0) on my Oracle Vbox virtual machine ( Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)
Also I have added tomcat 8 server to my Eclipse workspace.

Actually I am trying to create my first project based on this document https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/getting-started/getting-started-first-project but I am already facing some issues :)

I have selected Vaadin 7 project for a new project .
select Maven Archetype  ==>  Single module Application
window => specified Archetype parameters and clicked finished

After I have selected the project and Run As Maven Install and also compiled Vaadin themes.
Here are the issues I am having:

- When I compare my project hierarchy  with https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/getting-started/getting-started-first-project/#figure.getting-started.first-project.exploring I don't see JavaScript resources. It's important because my first task will be adding JavasScript to my application.

[image]

- When I am running the project as explained in the document:
  "*Starting your application is as easy as selecting myproject from the Project Explorer and then Run › Debug As › . Eclipse then opens the application in built-in web browser*"
  When I select run and Debug the **Debug on Server option is not available** ( only Java application , Maven Build etc)

  So I have tried another option: right click on Tomcat Server => Add or remove and I got the message: there are no resources that can be added or removed from the server
  Also tried :  Properties -> Projects Facets and check Dynamic Web Module but this doesn't help either

  When I am trying to run the project I am getting the message "The selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server"
  fre
  org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

  **I have also created the new Vaadin 10+ project with a "Base Starter for Vaadin" added Tomcat 8.0 Server ( maybe I should use Tomcat 9) and
  Getting the message "the selection cannot be run on any server" when trying to run the project.**

  Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Note that Vaadin 7 is no longer a publicly supported version. If you are starting a new project, you may want to start with the latest LTS version 14.

If you have a Spring Boot-based app (default), you can run it either with  `mvn spring-boot:run` Maven goal or by right-clicking the `Application.java` file and running it.

This documentation page outlines the steps for importing and running a Vaadin app in Eclipse: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/start/eclipse